# Configuration file not found - JBoss7

Tags: macos, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x

I wanted to deploy a simple jsp application: I created and copied the `myApp.war` file to the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployment` folder.

Instead of deploying the war file , JBoss created *.war.failed ,

So I thought maybe it's a good idea to restart the jboss to see if it affects the deployment.

In some forums it was suggested to restart the JBoss through : `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh` 
But there was no shutdown or restart command.

While I was trying to restart , I ran the following command :

```
/usr/local/jboss7/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c ":shutdown(restart=true)"
```

JBoss stopped working , but it didn't start again.

Now , I want to start it again by :

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh
```

But it gives me the following exception :

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/jboss7

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

17:29:43,399 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
17:29:43,536 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
17:29:43,567 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
17:29:43,876 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015956: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: JBAS014676: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:141) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:266) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:155) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '*' (code 42) (expected a name start character)
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [190,160]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedChar(StreamScanner.java:639)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.parseLocalName(StreamScanner.java:1798)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:2975)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2926)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2802)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1050)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.nextTag(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:152) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DeploymentScannerParser_1_1.readElement(DeploymentScannerParser_1_1.java:85)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner.DeploymentScannerParser_1_1.readElement(DeploymentScannerParser_1_1.java:28)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.handleAny(XMLExtendedStreamReaderImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.parseServerProfile(StandaloneXml.java:894) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readServerElement_1_1(StandaloneXml.java:330) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:127) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.server.parsing.StandaloneXml.readElement(StandaloneXml.java:100) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:110) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69) [staxmapper-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:133) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 3 more

17:29:43,882 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
17:29:43,889 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015950: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" stopped in 4ms
```

I searched for the cause of the problem , and I found that probably there's a problem with standalone.xml file.

In `/usr/local/jboss7/standalone/configuration/standalone_xml_history` I have the following files , but not the standalone.xml

```
2014xxxx-xxxxxxxx   
snapshot        
standalone.initial.xml
current         
standalone.boot.xml
standalone.last.xml
```

I'd like to know if I have to rename any of these files to `standalone.xml` ? (actually I tried renaming `standalone.boot.xml` to `standalone.xml` but it didn't work either !) or download a new one ? may I remove these xml files after having the new `standalone.xml` ?

Comment: try with restart your machine...

Comment: There should be better ways for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If JBoss-7 is installed in $JBOSSHOME, the default standalone configuration file is $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml; $JBOSSHOME/standalone/configuration is the default value of the jboss.server.config.dir property; and running $JBOSSHOME/bin/standalone.sh with no options will start JBoss in standalone mode on Linux/Unix systems.

In order to use a different standalone configuration file it can be renamed to standalone.xml, put in jboss.server.config.dir if it is not already there and standalone.sh run with no options; or its file name can be given to standalone.sh as an argument to its -c option after it is put in jboss.server.config.dir, for example:

```
$JBoss_home/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

RedHat documentation for this is at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters

I have had the best success with standalone/configuration/standalone-full.xml since it has the full configuration.  It is shipped with JBoss-7. If you don't have it you could download a fresh copy of the distro to get it. What I always do is archive a zip of the distro for recovery in case something gets corrupted or lost in the working copy.